# Kernel of the deriative of a polynomial on $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a ring and $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + · · · + a_nx^ n$ be in $F[x]$. Define $f '(x) = a_1 + 2a_2x + · · · + na_nx^{n−1}$ to be the derivative of $f(x)$

Calculate the kernel of $D$ if $charF = 0$.

Calculate the kernel of $D$ if $charF = p$

Can someone please explain ??

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find all polynomials for which $f'(x)=0$.

In order for $f'(x)=0$ you must have all coefficient equal to zero. Therefore
$$a_1=0 \\
2a_2 =0 \\
3a_3=0 \\
...\\
na_n =0 $$

Now, in characteristic $0$ all of $2,3,4,.., n$ are invertible, while in characteristic $p$ some of them are zero. You can finish it from here.

Comment: So I say D includes all the coefficients for charF=0?