# The kernel of $D$ if $char(F)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am attempting the part (b) and (c) of the following question from Judson:

[image]

I wrote this:  $ker(D) = \left \{ f(x) \in F[x] : f'(x) = 0\right \} =\left \{f'(x) = a_{1} + 2a_{2}x + \cdots + na_{n}x^{n-1} : a_{1} = 0, 2a_{2} = 0, ..., na_{n} = 0 \right \}$

For part (b), I followed this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035714). I am not sure why $char(F)=0$ implies $k$ of $ka_{n}$ is invertible for all $1\leq k \leq n$.

For part(c), I followed this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059705). I understood it until they said "polynomial in $x^{p}$". What does that mean?

Comment: Characteristic of any field is either $0$ or a prime number. Hence $k$ is invertible.

Comment: "$f(x)$ is polynomial in $x^p$" means that there is a polynomial $g \in F[x]$ such that $f(x) = g(x^p)$. More concretely, it means that every monomial in $f$ has a power that is divisible by $p$.  And as the comment above says, since $k$ and $a_n$ are nonzero, then $k a_n$ is invertible.

Comment: @André3000 Does that mean the kernel is the coefficients of $f'(x)$ when $char(F)=0$ and the kernel is the monomials in $f$ when $char(F) = p$? I am a little confused...

Comment: @YadatiKiran I am a little confused about how characteristic relates to invertibility? If there does not exist a positive integer $n$ such that $nr=0$ for all $r\in F$, why does that show that $r$ is invertible?

Comment: @numericalorange: What are the proper ideals of ring with characteristic $0$?

Comment: @YadatiKiran I see, so the characteristic is a generator of the kernel? So if $char(F)=0$, the kernel is the ideal $(0)$? And for $char(F)=p$, its kernel is $(p)$?

Comment: @numericalorange: Yes. If you are not able to clearly see try finding the kernel of $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ where $R$ is a ring with characteristic $m$.

Comment: @numericalorange I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. But I do see a mistake in my comment and the answer you linked. I (and the other poster, I assume) thought that $F$ was a field. But now I see it's only a ring (and not even assumed commutative, I guess...). So $n a_n$ is not necessarily invertible, but it is nonzero as $n$ and $a_n$ are nonzero.  The author should really be ashamed of calling the ring $F$, though: I think most people would assume that $F$ is a field.